# Outputting Information across Multiple Workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

*I hope this is clear enough - please comment if additional information is required.*

I have been asked to design an Excel / VBA tool which will display information on to a Summary worksheet based on user preferences. The home screen will ideally contain a top section having a number of checkboxes and dropdowns allowing the user to choose what information they would like to see: Finance, Activity & Customer Info. If the user selects Finance & Activity, this information will appear in 2 tables beneath.

The user will also see subsections i.e. Finance will include Balance & Arrears and like the above, the user can choose 1 or many of these to view information.

The dilemma I'm having is that the information is spread across different workbooks and I'm finding it difficult to find a quick and efficient method to extract data and output it to my worksheet. At the moment, I'm manually completing the process by conducting VLookups (each has a unique key) to create a Master spreadsheet and using pivots to display the information. This is too time consuming and isn't very visually appealling.

I'd like to use VBA to automate this process and have instant access to the information in the master spreadsheet based on user preferences.

It's also worth noting that this will be shared with users completely unfamiliar with Excel so I'm trying to veer away from the Drag & Drop Pivot Table approach.

If anyone has any suggestions on how I could create this system, you would be adding years on to my life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is an extensive VBA macro that you need. I will give you some guidance on how you can start coding it.

The main idea here is to copy all data from other Workbooks and paste them in different sheets of the Workbook you are using to visualize the data and then hide these sheets. In this way, you can interact with all the data using only one Workbook.

So how do you do this? I recomend the following link:
https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/copy-paste-another-workbook/

To **hide** sheets use `Sheets("sheet name").visible = false`

To **unhide** sheets use `Sheets("sheet name").visible = true`

For the purpose of maintaining data updated, one way could be setting the macro to run when opening the file.

Check this link: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/automatically-run-a-macro-when-opening-a-workbook-1e55959b-e077-4c88-a696-c3017600db44

Or you could just have a button to update.

**Note:** I've coded some VBA macros on Stackoverflow to move data between  Workbooks that could maybe help. You can find them in the **answers section** of my profile.

Comment: I was thinking something along these lines so thank you for confirming. Very useful information above - time to get to work!

Comment: @DannyO'Sullivan great to know!